# create trigger by checking the value of a field being inserted in oralce

Tags: oracle, triggers

I need to create a before insert trigger on `TABLE1` such that it inserts `COL2` and `COL3` of the new row being inserted in `TABLE1` into `TABLE2` only when `TABLE1.FIELD1 = 'XYZ'`. How do I do this so that trigger gets fired only when the condition is met?

Comment: first try with this doc http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_insert.php and raise the concern if you still cant accomplish.

Comment: Is it that the row being inserted on TABLE1 is referenced by :NEW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
   before insert 
   ON table_1
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.FIELD1 = 'XYZ'
  then
    INSERT INTO table_2 (col1, col2) VALUES (:NEW.col1, :NEW.col2);
  END IF;
END;
/
```

or how a_horse_with_no_name noted, your can use the the `WHEN` clause

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
   before insert 
   ON table_1
   FOR EACH ROW
   WHEN (NEW.FIELD1 = 'XYZ') 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO table_2 (col1, col2) VALUES (:NEW.col1, :NEW.col2);

END;
/
```

Comment: You can move that IF condition to the trigger definition so that the trigger isn't even fired if the column does not contain that value.